# Progress Bar using patoolib while extracting an archive

Tags: python

The title is self-explanatory

Is there a a built-in method to show progress at the moment it just:

> INFO patool: Extracting data/THE_Archive Extreme Edition.7z ...
> INFO patool: running C:\Windows\system32\7z.EXE x -oC:/Users/Administrator/Desktop -- "data/THE_Archive.7z"
> INFO patool:     with input=
> INFO patool: ... data/SharpShooter3D Extreme Edition.7z extracted to `C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop'